# Haskell Higher Order Function for reduce

Tags: haskell

Im working on this coding test practice for this class and came across this problem, and honestly am not too sure how to solve it, I was thinking on along the lines of using foldr for this, but not too sure how to approach this problem. Any guidance and explanation would be helpful thanks.

> Write a higher-order function called `lreduce` in Haskell that takes a two-parameter function `F` and a list `[a1,a2,...,an]` as arguments, and produces:

```
F(...F(F(a1,a2),a3)...,an)
```

The function decleration is :

```hs
lreduce :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
```

Comment: this is essentially `foldl1`

Comment: Sounds like `foldl1`, but you are probably asked to implement it from scratch. Surely you can lookup its implementation on the web, but I'd consider it cheating.

Comment: You can use recursion for this.

Comment: Start with the easy cases: `lreduce f [x]` and `lreduce f [x, y]`. That should give you some insights for how to handle the general case `lreduce f (x:xs)`. (Note that you cannot define `lreduce f []`, as the only source of a value of type `a` is from a non-empty list argument.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd write something like the following:

```hs
lReduce :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> a
lReduce _ []        = error "Empty lists not allowed"
lReduce _ [x]       = x
lReduce f [x, x']   = f x x'
lReduce f (x:x':xs) = lReduce f (f x x' : xs)
```

Running the following produces:

```
λ> lReduce (\x y -> "F(" ++ x ++ " " ++ y ++ ")" ) $ map show [1..10]
"F(F(F(F(F(F(F(F(F(1 2) 3) 4) 5) 6) 7) 8) 9) 10)"
```

Or similarly

```
λ> lReduce (\x y -> "(" ++ x ++ " `f` " ++ y ++ ")" ) $ map show [1..10]
"(((((((((1 `f` 2) `f` 3) `f` 4) `f` 5) `f` 6) `f` 7) `f` 8) `f` 9) `f` 10)"
```